# Get complete list of keyword arguments of an object's class

Tags: python

I want to find out the arguments of an object's method. The problem is that the arguments are optional so when I try either of the following, I don't get the required information

```
#1
import inspect
import pygraphviz as PG
sig = inspect.signature(PG.AGraph.add_node)

#2
full_arg = inspect.getfullargspec(PG.AGraph.add_node)

# 3
PG.AGraph.add_node.__defaults__
```

None of the above methods give the result I am looking for. For example, I know for a fact that the `add_node` function takes in arguments like `color`,`style` and others but I don't see them in either of these outputs. Is there a way to get this?

PS: The methods I mentioned above come from other SO questions addressing similar issues

Comment: What's preventing you from looking at the docs for `pygraphviz`?

Comment: There is no way to tell, if it is implemented by checking the `**kwargs` dict for specific values for example, other than by reading the source code

Comment: @FlyingTeller, I did open the docs. That was the first thing I did. Surprisingly it doesn't list out the `**kwargs`

Comment: Yeah, if they don't document `**attr` then you are SOL.

Comment: "See http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html for a list of attributes."

Comment: Quite long list of attributes, but contains all the information you might want. There are even visual examples for the various settings

Comment: @FlyingTeller, thanks a lot. This could help.